# Betatesting an android game. Best practices?

Tags: android, testing, playtesting

Our game is in our final stage prior to be released. I would like at this stage to add some beta testers to let them hunt bugs, etc... Is there any good platform/site to achieve this? I have noticed there's a site called betalizer but they still are in beta.

Could anyone suggest how to find beta testers for a little-medium size android game without spending a lot of bucks or any platform that could help on it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose the title is misleading, but I think [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18648/how-can-i-deploy-an-android-game-without-going-through-the-marketplace) might be a duplicate of this one (at least they're closely related. Like brothers.).

Answer (score 3):

[Google Play allows you to upload an alpha or beta version of your app and lets you choose a group of testers](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). The group can be a Google Group or Google+ Community. I highly recommend using social media to spread the word and involving (or hiring) interested people in beta testing. You can also hire people for few bucks on websites like [Fiverr.com](http://fiverr.com/gigs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=test%20android&order=&x=0&y=0).

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Fiverr, but I use it.